# String literal matching between words in two different dataframe (dfs) and generate a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, nltk, matching

I have two dataframes df1 and df2

df1 =

| University | School | Student first name | last name | nick name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Law | John | Mckenzie | Stevie |
| BBB | Business | Steve | Savannah | JO |
| CCC | Engineering | Mark | Justice | Fre |
| DDD | Arts | Stuart | Little | Rah |
| EEE | Life science | Adam | Johnson | meh |

120 rows X 5 columns

df2 =

| Statement |
| --- |
| Stuart had a headache last nigh which was due to th…… |
| Rah basically found a new found friend which lead to the…… |
| Gerome got a brand new watch which was………. |
| Adam was found chilling all through out his life…… |
| Savannah is such a common name that…….. |

3000 rows X1 columns

**AIM** is to form df3

Match the string literal and iterate it through every cells in the columns "Student first name" , "Student last name" , "Student nick name" to produce the table below

Df3  =

| Statement | Matching | University | School |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stuart had a headache last nigh which was due to th… | Stuart | DDD | Arts |
| Rah basically found a new found friend which lead to | Rah | DDD | Arts |
| Gerome got a brand new watch which was………. | NA | NA | NA |
| Adam was found chilling all through out his life…… | Adam | EEE | Life science |
| Savannah is such a common name that…….. | Savannah | BBB | Business |

3000 rows X 4 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import re

df1_melt = df1.melt(['University', 'School'], value_name='Match')

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, df1_melt['Match']))

out = df2.join(
 df1_melt[['Match', 'University', 'School']]
    .merge(df2['Statement']
              .str.extract(f'({regex})', expand=False)
              .rename('Match'),
           how='right', on='Match'
          )
)
```

output:

```
                                                  Statement     Match University        School
0      Stuart had a headache last nigh which was due to the    Stuart        DDD          Arts
1  Rah basically found a new found friend which lead to the       Rah        DDD          Arts
2                    Gerome got a brand new watch which was       NaN        NaN           NaN
3          Adam was found chilling all through out his life      Adam        EEE  Life science
4                       Savannah is such a common name that  Savannah        BBB      Business
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer makes the following assumptions:

- The index on `df1` serves as the student ID and is unique.
- That you only want to fill the first student found. A statement like "John and Steve are friends" will be assigned to John.

```py
import re

assigned = pd.Series([False] * len(df2))
df3 = df2.copy()

# Loop through each student, taking their first, last and nick name
for idx, names in df1[["Student first name", "last name", "nick name"]].iterrows():
    # If all statements have been assigned, terminate the loop
    if assigned.all():
        break

    # Combine the student's first, last and nick name into a regex pattern
    pattern = f"({'|'.join(names.map(re.escape))})"

    # For each UNASSIGNED statement, Find the pattern. We only search unassigned
    # statements to lower the number of searches.
    match = df3.loc[~assigned, "Statement"].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)

    # Mark the statement as assigned
    cond = ~assigned & match.notna()
    assigned[cond] = True

    # Fill in the student's info
    df3.loc[cond, "Match"] = match[cond]
    df3.loc[cond, "University"] = df1.loc[idx, "University"]
    df3.loc[cond, "School"] = df1.loc[idx, "School"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Naïve approach, loop columns to find matches then loop to merge on matches:

```
import re


columns_to_match = ["Student first name", "last name", "nick name"]

dfs = []
for column in columns_to_match:
    search_strings = df1[column].unique().tolist()

    regex = "|".join(map(re.escape, search_strings))
    df2["Matching"] = df2["Statement"].str.extract(f"({regex})")
    dfs.append(df2.dropna())

matched_df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)


dfs = []
for column in columns_to_match:
    final_df = df1.merge(matched_df, how="inner", left_on=column, right_on="Matching")
    dfs.append(final_df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns=columns_to_match)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating through each cell, you could create three dataframes (merging with all three columns separately) and concatenate the results into one dataframe.

```
df2['Matching'] = df2['Statement'].str.split().str[0]

dfs = []
for col in ['Student first name', 'last name', 'nick name']:
    df_temp = pd.merge(df2, df1[[col, 'University', 'School']].rename(columns={col:'Matching'}), how='left')
    dfs.append(df_temp)

df3 = pd.concat(dfs).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: The first statement gives me an error: `ValueError: Length of values (11) does not match length of index (5)`

Comment: @CodeDifferent thanks for catching that! Its updated and should work now.